# How can I manually get an access token using OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow in Azure Active Directory B2C?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

For testing purposes I am trying to manually get an access token. The guide [Request an access token in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens#request-a-token) basically describes two steps:

1. Get the authorization code - fine, no issue here
2. Using the authorization code, get an access token

I am having issues on step 2:

According to the instructions one shall make a `POST` request and specify https://jwt.ms as `redirect_uri`. I am using Postman to make this `POST` request, but in this case I have no chance to get the reply that is sent to https://jwt.ms ? So how could that work at all? Am I misunderstanding something? (I am still quite new to OAuth 2)

Comment: Are you getting any error while generating the access token?

Comment: In the POST request, you need to specify the value that you specified in step 1. When you acquire an authorization code, you must have specified a redirect_uri value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results as below:***

I created an **Azure AD Application and exposed an API**:

[image]

Now, I added the **API permissions** like below:

[image]

I generated the **auth-code** by using below endpoint:

```json
https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Signinsignup/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=7969b8c5-e6c6-49ab-b012-xxxxx
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/7969b8c5-e6c6-49ab-b012-d59xxxxx/test.read
&state=12345
```

[image]

I generated the **access token** using below parameters:

```json
https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Signinsignup/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:7969b8c5-e6c6-49ab-b012-d598a9d99d17
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/7969b8c5-e6c6-49ab-b012-xxxxxx/test.read
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

Comment: ah ok, got it, so I need to add a client secret (in Certificates & secrets) and use that. Thank you! Also: On the postman request one shouldn't forget to type the `https://` in front of the URL, otherwise it ends up with 404 while a real browser just redirects ;-)